# Problems with spark datasets

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset

When I execute a function in a mapPartition of dataset (executeStrategy()) it returns a result which I could check by debug but when I use dataset.show () it shows me an empty table and I do not know why this happens

This is for a data mining job at my school. I'm using windows 10, scala 2.11.12 and spark-2.2.0, which work without problems.

```
case class MyState(code: util.ArrayList[Object], evaluation: util.ArrayList[java.lang.Double])

private def executeStrategy(iter: Iterator[Row]): Iterator[(String,MyState)] = {
  val listBest = new util.ArrayList[State]
  Predicate.fuzzyValues = iter.toList

  for (i <- 0 until conf.runNumber) {
    Strategy.executeStrategy(conf.iterByRun, 1, conf.algorithm("algorithm").asInstanceOf[GeneratorType])
    listBest.addAll(Strategy.getStrategy.listBest)
  }

  val result = postMining(listBest)

  result.map(x => (x.getCode.toString, MyState(x.getCode,x.getEvaluation))).iterator
}

def run(sparkSession: SparkSession, n: Int): Unit = {
  import sparkSession.implicits._

  var data0 = conf.dataBase.repartition(n).persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
  var listBest = new util.ArrayList[State]

  implicit def enc1 = Encoders.bean(classOf[(String,MyState)])

  val data1 = data0.mapPartitions(executeStrategy)
  data1.show(3)
}
```

I expect that the dataset has the results of the processing of each partition, which I can see when I debug, but I get an empty dataset.
I have tried rdd with the same function `executeStrategy()` and this one returns an rdd with the results. What is the problem with the dataset?